# How do I exclude a file from batch execution?

Tags: java, batch-file, compilation

I wrote a batch file that compiles all .java files using javac:

```
javac *.java
```

But then I added another file, which I do not want to compile. For example let's name it ignored.java

Is there a way in batch programming to exclude something from code execution?

Something like:

```
javac *.java /except ignored.java
```

Comment: Use a `for` loop then use `if not "%%i" == "ignored.java"`. Something in the line of `for %%i in (*.java) do if /i not "%%~i" == "ignored.java" javac "%%~i"`

Comment: That worked. I tried something similar, but couldn't get the syntax right cause I'd never written batch before :p. Do you want to submit it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to use Argument File

Create a file named `classes` that contains only files to be compiled like following:

```
MyClass1.java
MyClass2.java
MyClass3.java
```

You can do that like this:

```sh
dir *.java /a:-d /b|find /i /v "ignored.java">classes
```

Then, run the javac command as follows:

```
javac @classes
```

As ignored.java is not mentioned in classes file, it will be skipped

Comment: Thank you for answering. This solution does solve the problem outlined above, however it is not scalable.

If it needs to be run on a folder with hundreds of .java files it wouldn't make sense to write a file containing all files that need to be compiled instead of just listing them with a single javac command.

Comment: @MiroslavMilanov there's a benefit in doing so. Using a `@filename` means that you can process a few thousand files as a single process, i.e. you're only running one javac.exe process, with a list of filename arguments of unrestricted length. The `for` loop method will run one javac process for every file it finds, which is likely to be intensive. Additionally writing out to a single file is a very quick process, and is unlikely to add any noticeable overhead. Please try this method against the for loop one for varying numbers of files, and compare their execution times, they may surprise you.

Comment: That's actually a really good point. I did notice that the commands with the other question are computed one at a time and I had assumed it was the same for this solution as well. Thank you for pointing that out. I take my words about scalability back, this is infinitely better.

Answer (score 2):

`cmd` requires a `for` loop to do something `for` each item. `if` can be used to compare. That will give you a solution of:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.java) do if /i not "%%~i" == "ignored.java" javac "%%~i"
```

Note also the `/i` switch for `if` which makes the comparison case insensitive.